# Laravel Nova Delete Resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have created a model and resource but then decided to change the name of the model. So I renamed everything in the model and the migration as well as the resource. But in Nova, the old name still appears. I deleted the resource file and created a new one with `php artisan nova:resource xxx` but the old name keeps appearing in the Nova sidebar and it can't find the right database table. I cleared the cache (`php artisan cache:clear`) as well as the composer autoload (`composer dump-autoload`). What else do I to change?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that Laravel uses "people" as plural for "person", I expected it to be "persons". That's the reason why it keeps looking for the people table.